# Logarithmic Slider: Shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, slider, shiny

I have modified the Shiny slider so that it displays 10^(slider number) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2_rKFnvrjMAWkZoOXBpOVVXZms/edit?usp=sharing).

The file goes in  ...\R\win-library\3.0\shiny\www\shared\slider\js. you can test it out by replacing `jquery.slider.min.js` with this file.

I am not very proficient at javascript and web programming. How should I name this new slider, and how can I use it in my shiny program along with the regular slider?

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed and [tag:javascript] tag added. You will want to be sure that you look up and understand the significant difference between these two languages.

Comment: You would need to create a shiny binding to this js file. For examples see ZJ's [ShinySky](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky) package on github